# Consume records from more than one topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been working on Kafka streams coding. Trying to create some samples first to understand.

I tried subscribing to one topic with the below `Consumer` code, and it is working fine.

```
try {
              while (true) {
                  consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
                  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);

                  for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                      // To Retrieve Data in this Consumer
                      System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value() );            
                  }
              }
        } finally {
          consumer.close();
        }
```

When I want to consume multiple topics, i tried the below sample,

```
try {
          while (true) {
              consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic, topic1));
              ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);

              for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                  // To Retrieve Data in this Consumer
                  System.out.println("Received message: " + record.value() );            
              }
          }
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
```

But this is receiving record only from one topic, not from both topics. Can someone please guide me how can i consume records from more than one topic?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Why do you think no data is returned from the second topic? What version do you use?

Comment: It is working already. I have missed logging in properly. Btw, thank you so much for reviewing.